# Android X onMenuItemSelected

Tags: android, android-jetpack

After existing project was refactored to android.x, I got error, that `onMenuItemSelected` method cannot be overridden. 'Cause in `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity` this method is final. 
How can I handle clicks by menu now?

EDIT: 
Seems, like this change not only on androidx, but in support 27

Answer (score 0):

It is depends of which type of menu you want handle. Android has Context menu, and Options menu. `onMenuItemSelected` - it is the general callback of such menu type's.

So, for click on Context menu you should use `onContextItemSelected` methods,

for Options Menu `onOptionsItemSelected`